# Minbucket not working when producing trees with CHAID package

Tags: r, tree

I have been trying to ensure that a classification tree that I obtain using the CHAID algorithm implemented in the CHAID package will produce a tree with terminal nodes (leafs) with at least `minbucket` number of observations. According to the description of the chaid procedure this can be done by specifying a `chaid_control` function:

```
chaid_control(alpha2 = 0.05, alpha3 = -1, alpha4 = 0.05,
              minsplit = 20, minbucket = 7, minprob = 0.01,
              stump = FALSE, maxheight = -1)
```

This is similar behavior to controlling trees in the rpart package.

Nevertheless, setting the `minbucket` parameter seems not to have any influence on the final shape of the resulting tree. Here is an example:

```
library("CHAID")
set.seed(290875)
USvoteS <- USvote[sample(1:nrow(USvote), 1000),]
chaid(vote3 ~ ., data = USvoteS)

Model formula:
vote3 ~ gender + ager + empstat + educr + marstat

Fitted party:
[1] root
|   [2] marstat in married
|   |   [3] educr <HS, HS, >HS: Gore (n = 311, err = 49.5%)
|   |   [4] educr in College, Post Coll: Bush (n = 249, err = 35.3%)
|   [5] marstat in widowed, divorced, never married
|   |   [6] gender in male: Gore (n = 159, err = 47.8%)
|   |   [7] gender in female
|   |   |   [8] ager in 18-24, 25-34, 35-44, 45-54: Gore (n = 127, err = 22.0%)
|   |   |   [9] ager in 55-64, 65+: Gore (n = 115, err = 40.9%)

Number of inner nodes:    4
Number of terminal nodes: 5
```

The terminal nodes 3, 4, 6, 8, and 9 consist of 311, 249, 159, 127, and 115 observations, respectively. Now, normally, in order to constrain the minimal number of observations one should proceed as follows:

```
ctrl <- chaid_control(minbucket = 200)
```

Nevertheless, invoking

```
chaid(vote3 ~ ., data = USvoteS, control = ctrl)
```

yields the same tree as before (instead of a tree with nodes with at least 200 observations).

I am not sure whether it is I who makes a mistake or something is missing in the implementation of the `chaid` procedure...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The minimum number of observations in each terminal node is controlled by `minbucket` and `minprob`. The former gives the absolute number of observations, the latter the relative frequency (relative to the sample size of the current node). Internally, the *minimum* of both quantities is used in each node. This was also counterintuitive for me as I would have expected the *maximum* to be used - but I didn't check whether the original CHAID algorithm is described in this way.

If you want to make sure that only `minbucket` controls the minimum node size, then set `minbucket = 200, minprob = 1`.

Comment: Thanks! This solves the problem and now everything works as expected! Just by the way, have you learned about the _minimum_ of both quantities being used (perhaps instead of _maximum_) by inspecting the code, or is this based on some other knowledge?